# zsh installed via cygwin makes the windows background sound with every command

Tags: terminal, cygwin, zsh, visual-studio-code

So I have zsh.exe inside C:\cygwin64\bin and I recently integrated it as an integrated terminal for vs code. I have noticed it makes the windows background sound with every command I enter in the terminal. Has anyone else had this issue? Thanks. I am running windows 8.1

On a side note when I try to run C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty as the path for vscode it launches Cygwin as an external terminal rather than internally through vscode. I have seen suggestions to use the bash.exe within the same path but this removes the style.

Comment: Maybe it’s the terminal bell...? // Mintty is a terminal emulator. It cannot be used inside another terminal emulator (VS Code).

Comment: It is strange because it somehow worked before? I am pretty sure I had a path linked to the terminal which worked but not it launches it separately.

Comment: I tried turning the terminal bell off through the set terminal bell command or something along those lines but that did not work.